# How to tell the gcc to look in the include folder for the header files?

Tags: c, gcc, header, include

I'm using c. And I have a `include` folder inside my project `myProject/include` and inside I have all the header files from the SDK I downloaded from the Internet. So my question is how can I tell the `gcc` to look for the header files inside the include folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-I` option with `gcc` to tell the path where to look for the header files.

From [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

> `-Idir`
>   Add the directory `dir` to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files. This can be used to override a system header file, substituting your own version, since these directories are searched before the system header file directories. [...]

You can use this option multiple times,

> [...] If you use more than one `-I` option, the directories are scanned in left-to-right order; the standard system directories come after.