# Cannot compile, error: cryptlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries, crypto++

I've downloaded Crypto++ 7.0.0 from the official site, build a static library out of it, included cryptlib header with:

```
#include "cryptlib.h"
```

and when I try to compile my program with:

```
gcc main.cpp ./cryptopp700/libcryptopp.a
```

it throws at me errors like this:

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: cryptlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cryptlib.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried with:

```
-L. -llibcryptopp //while moving libcryptopp.a to the same directory main.cpp is
-L./cryptopp700 -llibcryptopp
```

so I started wondering if I was doing something wrong, but as I was checking out code examples with static libraries, everything seemed to be fine.

Help please.

Comment: You need to pass location of all directories where you want to include files from with `-I` switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell the gcc to look in the include folder for the header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346866/how-to-tell-the-gcc-to-look-in-the-include-folder-for-the-header-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on:

> ```
> main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: cryptlib.h: No such file or directory
> ```

And:

> ```
> gcc main.cpp ./cryptopp700/libcryptopp.a
> ```

Your directory structure looks like:

```
+- Project Folder
  |
  +- main.cpp
  |
  +- cryptopp700
    |
    +- cryltib.h
    +- ...
    +- libcryptopp.a
```

You should only need to add `cryptopp700/` to your include header search path with `-I`:

```
g++ main.cpp -I ./cryptopp700 ./cryptopp700/libcryptopp.a
```

Note that you should also use ***g++*** (the C++ compiler), not ***gcc*** (the C compiler).

---

You can also install the library since it has been built. By default it installs into `/usr/local` with:

```
skylake:cryptopp$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for jwalton:
install -m 644 *.h /usr/local/include/cryptopp
install -m 644 libcryptopp.a /usr/local/lib
install cryptest.exe /usr/local/bin
install -m 644 TestData/*.dat /usr/local/share/cryptopp/TestData
install -m 644 TestVectors/*.txt /usr/local/share/cryptopp/TestVectors
```

You can install into an alternate location using `PREFIX`:

```
skylake:cryptopp$ sudo make install PREFIX=/opt/local
install -m 644 *.h /opt/local/include/cryptopp
install -m 644 libcryptopp.a /opt/local/lib
install cryptest.exe /opt/local/bin
install -m 644 TestData/*.dat /opt/local/share/cryptopp/TestData
install -m 644 TestVectors/*.txt /opt/local/share/cryptopp/TestVectors
```

Then, you would change you compile and link command to something like:

```
g++ main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/cryptopp -o main.exe /usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
```

---

After an install like shown below, I normally tell folks to run the self tests. Unfortunately, the won't work if all you did was a `make -j 4` or similar.

```
$ make -j 4
...

$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for jwalton:
install -m 644 *.h /usr/local/include/cryptopp
install -m 644 libcryptopp.a /usr/local/lib
install cryptest.exe /usr/local/bin
install -m 644 TestData/*.dat /usr/local/share/cryptopp/TestData
install -m 644 TestVectors/*.txt /usr/local/share/cryptopp/TestVectors
```

Here's the error you would get:

```
skylake:cryptopp$ cd /opt/local/bin/
skylake:bin$ ./cryptest.exe v
Using seed: 1544189072

Testing Settings...

passed:  Your machine is little endian.
passed:  Aligned data access.
passed:  sizeof(byte) == 1
passed:  sizeof(word16) == 2
passed:  sizeof(word32) == 4
passed:  sizeof(word64) == 8
passed:  sizeof(word128) == 16
passed:  sizeof(hword) == 4, sizeof(word) == 8, sizeof(dword) == 16
passed:  cacheLineSize == 64
hasSSE2 == 1, hasSSSE3 == 1, hasSSE4.1 == 1, hasSSE4.2 == 1, hasAVX == 1, hasAVX2 == 1, hasAESNI == 1, hasCLMUL == 1, hasRDRAND == 1, hasRDSEED == 1, hasSHA == 0, isP4 == 0
...

SHA validation suite running...

Exception caught: Can not open file TestVectors/sha.txt for reading
```

My thinking is things should "just work" for you. You should not need to worry about `CRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR` for a common case. And you certainly should not have to RTFM to make the common case work. That tells me there's a defect in our engineering process.

We are going to fix that now: Issue 760, [Make self-tests run after install by a typical user](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/760).

Answer (score 0):

For me installing the development crypt library solved the issue:

```
apt-get install libcrypt-devel
```